# delete a cron xml having over quota situation without waiting

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, jdo

after some days playing with the app engine I managed to block my app.
The situation is that I deployed a project into GAE with a cron job running every 2 mins and it run out of cpu time (currently 6.5hours every 24 hours). And being a cron job it keeps running and running.
I can´t upload a plain cron.xml to remove the old one because I have not cpu quota, so I have to wait until the 24 hours deadline resets my quota time.

Is there a way to remove a cron in this situation without having to wait until the deadline?? (it would be so simple if google had provided a "delete cron" button in the admin panel...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need CPU quota to upload a new version of your app. Just upload an empty one using the standard deployment process.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I was getting a 500 error message while uploading so I though it was due to quota limits.